# How to enable column resize on MUI DataGrid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

How do I enable column resize for user on MUI DataGrid, it is enable by default on XGrid, but I want to enable it on Datagrid, please help.

```html
   <DataGrid
       className={classes.table}                
       autoHeight
       disableColumnMenu
       rows={rows}
       columns={columns}
       pageSize={50}
       onPageChange={handlePageChange}
       rowCount={rowCount}
       paginationMode="server"
       loading={loading}
       rowsPerPageOptions={[]}
     />
```

Comment: There is a prop `resizable` on `GridColDef` interface. You provide list of column definitions to the `columns` prop on `DataGrid`. Maybe the solution is to set it on column level.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately [resizable columns](https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/) are available only in the comercial version (XGrid).